# How to change Dojo ComboButton label by MenuItem choice?

Tags: combobox, dojo

Can I change a ComboButton's label by clicking the menu Item it owns? I try to do this by:

```
var menu_item=new MenuItem({
    label:search_types_value[key].display_name,
    onClick:function(){
        search_type_button.label="hi";
    search_type_button.startup();
    }
});

var search_type_button=new ComboButton({
    id:"search_type_button",
    label:"types",
    dropDown: search_type_menu
},"search_type_button");
```

However, this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, this looks like a scope issue. `search_type_button` isn't available in the onClick function. Instead of providing the onclick function directly to the menu item, use `.connect` to wire the `onClick` to the function you want to execute.

```
var menu_item=new MenuItem({
    label:search_types_value[key].display_name,
});

var search_type_button=new ComboButton({
    id:"search_type_button",
    label:"types",
    dropDown: search_type_menu
},"search_type_button");

search_type_button.connect(menu_item, 'onClick', function() {
    var newLabel = 'hi';
    this.set('label', newLabel);
});
```

Comment: newer versions of dojo use on() vs connect()